# File write not correct

Tags: string, visual-c++, text-files

I'm writing some strings to a file using the following function...

```
void writeText(const char* desc){
        FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("CycleTestInfo.txt","a+");
    fputs (desc,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

...inside of a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<numCycles; i++){
    string cycle("---NEW CYCLE ");
    cycle+=(char)i;
    cycle+= "---\r\n";
    writeText(cycle.c_str());
}
```

I have two issues though.`i` doesnt show up in my textfile and the newline does not appear for the first string written in my text file. For example, if numCycles is 4, I get the following output in my textfile.

```
---NEW CYCLE Cycle Done!

---NEW CYCLE ---

Cycle Done!

---NEW CYCLE ---

Cycle Done!

---NEW CYCLE ---

Cycle Done!
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
---NEW CYCLE 1---

Cycle Done!

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`i` doesnt show up in my textfile***
It's because you are writing character with [ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60ecse8t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) value `1`. Value of character `'1'` is different and can be easily retrieved by adding value of `'0'` to `i` like this: `char c = '0' + i;`

***the newline does not appear for the first string written in my text file***
First time `i` is equal to `0` which is also the value of the terminating character `'\0'`

Check out this article: [C++ Character Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt `(char)i` is the way to go there, you should try `(char)((int)'0' + i)`